# 1054 Unknown column 'a.extra_query' in 'field list' SQL=SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, upgrade

I'm finally upgrading Joomla 2.5 to 3.9 with a step to 3.5.1.

However, whatever I try, I keep getting this

> error: 1054 Unknown column 'a.extra_query' in 'field list' SQL=SELECT DISTINCT a.update_site_id, a.type, a.location, a.last_check_timestamp, a.extra_query FROM #__update_sites AS a INNER JOIN #__update_sites_extensions AS b ON a.update_site_id = b.update_site_id WHERE a.enabled = 1 AND b.extension_id IN (700)

I tried uninstalling templates, extensions, plugins, but nothing helps.
After this error website is no longer accessible.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Comment: Please do some Googling before posting a question to avoid generating redundant site content.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that in `#__update_sites` table in your **database** the column named `extra_query` is missing, thus the query cannot be executed. The easiest way to handle this error is creating an `extra_query` column in that table. You can do that via **phpMyAdmin** area on your server account. There are a lot of easy instructions of how to do that, I just link one here:

https://www.pair.com/support/kb/adding-a-column-to-a-database-in-phpmyadmin/

The field type might be set to `TEXT` type (it could be VARCHAR or other type but TEXT is OK and later can be changed).

During the upgrade there probably will be few similar issues (and probably some worse than this issue). So maybe it is better to turn on `development mode` in global configuration of your Joomla to see the full stack of errors if/when those happen...

Comment: You might like to transfer this answer to the original in case this duplicate page gets deleted.

Comment: Oops, i didn’t check that, it could be deleted then...

Comment: Thanks Zollie. After trying this, the one after the other error appeared so I will decide to create a new site and import the old stuff.